# Creating new instance values for each member of a class

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

Here's what I want to do, and couldn't:

I am instantiating devices belonging to various classes (models). Let's say it's cars. The instantiated cars should inherit "default" attributes depending on the model, but should have each his own. Example of class hierarchy:

```
Car
  Tesla
  Honda
Property
```

"Property" would be a `<key, value>` pair, for example, `<"top_speed", "100">`, `<"seats", 5>`.
I can define default properties for, say, Tesla, creating the instances:

```
teslaPropertySpeed = <"top_speed", 100>
teslaPropertySeats = <"seats", 5>
```

and then make all Teslas have the property:

```
Tesla SubClassOf ((hasProperty value teslaPropertySpeed) and (hasProperty value teslaPropertySeats))
```

...however, if I buy a Tesla, I might "hack it" to make it go faster or slower, or remove seats. Because I said that all Teslas have that property, it wouldn't be a Tesla anymore.

A better way would be saying that all Teslas have THEIR OWN speed and seat properties, which I would like to set to a default, modifiable value.

In a nutshell, I would like to create NEW properties for each instantiated Tesla. Can I do that declaratively? As for default values, I would be fine defining the default values in a subclass of Tesla (say, FactoryTesla), so that a modified Tesla would be knocked off of that subclass, but would retain the upper "Tesla" class.

Comment: it looks like you already found a way by introducing sibling subclasses which simply "refine" the more generic properties stated in the superclass. So what does not work? And don't, OWL inference monotonic. And it's not based on default logic but FOL (resp. its decidable fragment description logic)

Comment: What doesn't work is that I do not want all Teslas to be linked to the same Property individual, but each to his own, and I'm looking for a way to make this happen automatically upon the creation of a new Tesla instance, rather than having to create the new Property individuals for it by hand. The statement I'm trying to make is "each Tesla has their own top speed and number of seats, which has the same value for all of them as they come out of the factory". I suppose I could just create the new Property individual for the modified Tesla, though, detaching it from the default one.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do what you intend to do. That is to be able to infer that a car that is of type `Tesla` is no longer of type `Tesla` because it has been modified. As AKSW has pointed out, this cannot happen due to inferencing being monotonic. This roughly means that whatever has been inferred before adding further axioms will still be inferred after adding further axioms. The only way to "loose" inferences is to modify or delete existing axioms in your ontology.

What you **will be able to do** is to define the properties of your `Tesla` class and allow the reasoner to infer that an individual is of type `Tesla`. The following ontology will do just that.

```
DataProperty: hasSeats
    Range: xsd:integer


DataProperty: hasTopSpeed
    Range: xsd:integer


Class: Car
    EquivalentTo: 
        (hasSeats exactly 1 xsd:integer)
         and (hasTopSpeed exactly 1 xsd:integer)


Class: Tesla
    EquivalentTo: 
        (hasSeats value 5)
         and (hasTopSpeed value 100)
    SubClassOf: 
        Car


Individual: aTesla
    Facts:  
     hasSeats  5,
     hasTopSpeed  100

Individual: notATesla
    Facts:  
     hasSeats  2,
     hasTopSpeed  80
```

This will infer that the `aTesla` individual is of type `Tesla`, while no such inference will be made for the individual `notATesla`. However, if you create an individual `modifiedTesla` as below, this will result in the reasoner giving an inconsistency.

```
Individual: modifiedTesla
    Type: Tesla
    Facts: hasTopSpeed  200
```

The reason for the inconsistency (for the ontology as above) is because `modifiedTesla` is related twice via the `hasTopSpeed` property: Once for `hasTopSpeed 100` and once for `hasTopSpeed 200`. This is because `hasTopSpeed 200` **does not override** the properties in the `Tesla` class.

From your question you seem to approach this from an object oriented perspective. There are some similarities, but for the most part object orientation and ontologies are worlds apart. I have written about some of the pitfalls that trip people up in this regard [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/04/15/object-oriented-features-that-owl-lacks/).

Comment: Actually, the individual losing the fact of being a Tesla would be an UNINTENDED side effect I would like to avoid, not achieve. My problem is actually declaring that each new Tesla individual should be created alongside HIS OWN properties. I don't want them all to share the same Property individuals, only share properties with the same default values.